# Notepad++ Regular Expression for Selected Group Line Number Before the Lines Group Start

Tags: notepad++

I am using this regular expression in Notepad++ `(?-s)^(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R` and want to get the below output if I have multiple lines:

```
358
293
866
511
58
767
562
644
163
569
414
305
973
16
692
128
353
1000
870
58
535
866
```

However, I want to get output like this, adding the number in `@@i@@` of the group that is selected:

```
@@1@@358
293
866
@@2@@511
58
767
@@3@@562
644
163
@@4@@569
414
305
@@5@@973
16
692
@@6@@128
353
1000
@@7@@870
etc
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `add_num.py`):

```
import re

counter = 0
def add_num(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return '@@' + str(counter) + '@@' + match.group(1)

editor.rereplace(r'^(\d+\R\d+\R\d+\R?)', add_num)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> add_num)
- Done

**Result for given example:**

[image]